# Android application would not stop crashing despite its simplicity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently making a very very simple Android app, following this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-textbox-example/

In my `fragment_main.xml`, I have this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

In my `MainActivity.java`, I have the following. It's simply an app that responds to key presses.

```
private EditText edittext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    addKeyListener();
}

public void addKeyListener()
{
    // get edittext component
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    // add a keylistener to keep track of user input

    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                // display a floating message
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            else if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9))
            {
                // display a floating message
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number 9 is pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The app basically responds to key presses.

Everything I have up top are the only things I have changed from the stock application. The target was 4.3 on my Note 3.

My app runs fine if it is a Hello World app (the stock app you create with Eclipse), however, as soon as I add additional components/methods to it, it would simple get me **unfortunately, myapp has stopped**.

I have tried creating a new project *just* for this new example, but the same errors of the application crashing.

I was wondering does anyone know why this is happening. Compilation does not tell me any warnings/errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Need to post the logcat

Comment: Thanks guys. I will post logcat in a couple minutes.

Comment: It appears this may be of relevance: http://puu.sh/949Zg/67d8f3228e.png

Comment: I was unable to find `data/log` on my phone.

Comment: I guess this is due to NullPointerException since first: your contentView is the activity_main layout and your fragment is fragment_main layout where the EditText is placed. Since that one is a fragment you also need to get the layout out there. Try locating your class that extends that Fragment and apply it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is :

edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

because editText component is in fragment_main.xml , not the current activity's contentview  activity_main.xml, so the value of variable edittext must be null, then the following code will cause error.

please move the method addKeyListener() into PlaceholderFragment class, then it will be ok.

Comment: Exactly, also the Tutorial he shared is already outdated. That one doesn't implement a Fragment at all.

Comment: Hi lxh2002. Where do I call `addKeyListener()`?

Comment: I also implemented `addKeyListener()` within my previous class. Does this mean I also have to implement `addKeyListener()` within `fragment_view`'s static class?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution is simple.Your EditText resides in `fragment_main.xml` and you are using
**activity_main** with setContentView() in your java file.Hence there will be a **nullpointer exception**.The solution is :change  **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** to 
 **setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);**

Comment: Hi @kgandroid. Seems like your method is simpler than what the others suggested, that is putting stuff into `PlaceholderFragment`. I'll test it out on my phone soon.